# How to update the quanity to a selected one in a shopping cart?

Tags: php, wordpress

Have a function in my functions.php

This will change the quanity input to the dropdown with the specific values.

```
function woocommerce_quantity_input($data) {
    global $product;
  $defaults = array(
    'input_name'    => $data['input_name'],
    'input_value'   => $data['input_value'],
    'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
    'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
    'step'    => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
    'style'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left; margin-right:10px;', $product )
  );
  if ( ! empty( $defaults['min_value'] ) )
    $min = $defaults['min_value'];
  else $min = 1;
  if ( ! empty( $defaults['max_value'] ) )
    $max = $defaults['max_value'];
  else $max = 20;
  if ( ! empty( $defaults['step'] ) )
    $step = $defaults['step'];
  else $step = 1;
  $options = '';
  for ( $count = $min; $count <= $max; $count = $count+$step ) {
    $selected = $count === $defaults['input_value'] ? ' selected' : '';
    $options .= '<option value="' . $count . '"'.$selected.'>' . $count . '</option>';
  }
  echo '<div class="quantity_select" style="' . $defaults['style'] . '"><select name="' . esc_attr( $defaults['input_name'] ) . '" title="' . _x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) . '" class="qty">' . $options . '</select></div>';
}
```

The problem with this function is that it also changes quanity to dropdown in cart as well and sets default to 1.

User case:

User selects 1.5 amount of the product that costs 10 $ on the single product page. Then proceeds to checkout. Then in the cart there is a price of 15$ and the quanity is 1.

I see two ways of fixing it.

One is including the function to only single page, but not sure how its done. Tried with if $product->type == 'product' inside the function but since this overrides the original one the dropdown wont be shown on the cart page at all.

The best way is to update the dropdown with the selected amount/value in the cart.

Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
var_dump($data) output;

```
array(4) { ["input_name"]=> string(43) "cart[ec3686cdd117b8c6b8992f22e04a415b][qty]" ["input_value"]=> int(1) ["max_value"]=> NULL ["min_value"]=> string(1) "0" } 1
```

after updating the value in the cart the input_value becomes to float:

```
array(4) { ["input_name"]=> string(43) "cart[ec3686cdd117b8c6b8992f22e04a415b][qty]" ["input_value"]=> float(2.2) ["max_value"]=> NULL ["min_value"]=> string(1) "0" } 2.2
```

Comment: Should the user only be able to select whole numbers or do you want to support decimal values?

Comment: User should be able to use decimals yes.

Comment: Can you dump out what the values are for each variable, especially  `$step`?

Comment: Yes, step is 1. The problem is when you set the minimum value = 1 it sets 1 as a startint point both for single page and for the checkout page. It makes sense to have it on single page but i can't find a way to exclude the checkout page.

Comment: 1 is being selected because it's the first value, not because it matches the input value. If your step doesn't support decimals then you will never get a match for `$selected`. I'll put up an answer that should work.

Comment: It is supported, I have been experimenting with simplier function without a dropdown https://pastebin.com/z0VRCLX6 and had no issues with it. But when the loop the select does not have selected amount in the cart in the first function i've displayed.

Comment: Sorry I've just checked the cart and it only has whole numbers. My bad. Any way to fix this? UPDATE: it was because i had removed defaults, after adding them again it is displayed in decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to support decimals, your step will also need to support decimals or at least insert the selected value as a value.

Create a value specifically for whatever the user selected if count bypasses it (`$step` is 1, `$data['input_value']` is a decimal):

```
function woocommerce_quantity_input($data) 
{
    global $product;

    $defaults = array(
        'input_name'  => $data['input_name'],
        'input_value' => $data['input_value'],
        'max_value'   => apply_filters('woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product),
        'min_value'   => apply_filters('woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product),
        'step'        => apply_filters('woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product),
        'style'       => apply_filters('woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left; margin-right:10px;', $product),
    );

    // Work out values
    $min = !empty($defaults['min_value']) ? $defaults['min_value'] : 1;
    $max = !empty($defaults['max_value']) ? $defaults['max_value'] : 20;
    $step = !empty($defaults['step']) ? $defaults['step'] : 1;

    $options = '';

    $lastValue = 0;
    for ($count = $min; $count <= $max; $count = $count + $step) {
        // Check if input value is between last value and current value, if it is create a value specifically for the selected value
        if ($defaults['input_value'] > $lastValue && $defaults['input_value'] < $count) {
            $options .= '<option value="' . $defaults['input_value'] . '" selected="selected">' . $defaults['input_value'] . '</option>';
        }

        $selected = $count === $defaults['input_value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
        $options .= '<option value="' . $count . '"'.$selected.'>' . $count . '</option>';

        // Update last value to current value
        $lastValue = $count;
    }

    echo '<div class="quantity_select" style="' . $defaults['style'] . '"><select name="' . esc_attr($defaults['input_name']) . '" title="' . _x('Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce') . '" class="qty">' . $options . '</select></div>';
}
```

Alternatively you could change the step to be decimals:

```
$step = !empty($defaults['step']) ? $defaults['step'] : 0.1;
```

Comment: I did some testing and I get the same output. Prices are rounded down. Case: i take 2.5 in the cart quantity dropdwon will still show 1, and the price will be for 2.0, this is exaclty the same output I had for previous code.

Comment: What is in `$data['input_value']` when you select 2.5?

Comment: seems like it is always 1

Comment: That seems to be the actual problem, the code I provided will create a value even if it doesn't exist in the loop.

Comment: Should i remove it ?

Comment: You need to find the correct variable which contains the data the user selected then your script will work.

Comment: Ok thats great, any idea on how i find it. The only thing i found in headers was this
------WebKitFormBoundaryBYJ2d4aAbR05iiG5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="quantity"

1.3

Comment: Add the output of `var_dump($data);` to your original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146359/discussion-between-giedrius-and-sjdaws).